# Showing item-level & order-level offers/promotions on Details page (PDP) &/or Cart page?

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, mobile-application, e-commerce, mobile-web

**I have 2 types of offers (promotions) applicable on my eCommerce website**:

- Item level offers (example: Item belongs to Brand XYZ. Buy any 2 items from brand XYZ to get 30% off)
- Order level offers (example: $10 off on total purchase of $100 worth of items)

**Journey of user will be**: User will go to the Details page of an item, User will see all the item-level offers applicable to the item, user will add the item to the cart, user will come to the Cart page.

**Assumption**: The user has added 5-6 items in the Cart page, and each of these items has 2-3 item-level offers associated with it, and there are 2-3 order-level offers applicable too.

**Question is**:

- Where should I list the item-level offers associated with the item?
- Where should I list the order-level offers?

**Possible options**:

- Showing item-level offers only on Details page
- Showing item-level offers only on Cart page
- Showing order-level offers only on Details page
- Showing order-level offers only on Cart page
- Showing item-level offers only on both Details page & Cart page
- Showing order-level offers only on both Details page & Cart page

Comment: Try each one and see which performs best.

Comment: I would probably avoid showing offers _only_ on the details page... on some websites, if I was (re)ordering an item I'd bought before, I might not revisit the details page and might miss the offers.

Answer (score 1):

you can give some add coupons options on product details page.
So user can apply any coupon or offer for single product/products.

So next on cart also give a option to add coupons/check for offers.

This would be confusing for user .
But try doing A/B testing , and check if it's helping.

Answer (score 1):

Promotions should be shown anywhere were they are relevant. Homepage, product listing, product detail pages should all have mentions of relevant promotions to serve as a incentive for the user to add to cart.

**Item Level Promotions**

- Featured in Homepage: You want users to see which item specials they can profit on today. Much like supermarket circulars or any ecommerce store. Consider listing out many of these in a grid to grab enough people's interests.
- List in Product Listings: These promotions act like single products (or bundles). Product A = A$, Product A+B = AB$. So the user can see side by side, compare and discover visually. Your goal is to get them to think "I see, if I purchase these 2 together, I save this much"
- List in Product Details: Below the product's information, you can start listing the bundles again for upsell. Amazon and Walmart do this. If you buy A+B = You pay $ and save $.
- Cart: you can also show these in the cart, but to a lesser extent. Users coming into the cart already have their mind made-up and may want to see just a list of what they are buying. You may want to add a small mention of how much they could save and a link to see what they should buy to save that $. This may open the listing page with a special personalized savings filter applied.

**Order Level Promotions**

- Show in homepage, just to make users aware of the concept as they are shopping for products.
- Show in cart, let the user know how much they saved due to how much they bought and promotion applied.

**Note**
These suggestions might contradict each other. I would encourage you to AB test each scenario and see how the user reacts to the promotions. You can do a quick prototype test in the office with unfamiliar people to the project if budget is short.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, promote your special offers broadly. Promote them on the homepage, on social media, on category pages and the PDPs.

The usual pattern seems to be promoting Item-Level Offers on the PDP, Product Detail Page and Order-Level Offers in the Cart.